# Dynamic array of hashes in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, erb, sinatra-activerecord

**I have an array of hashes that I want to dynamically change the content on the page with.** How do I show all the names of the hashes and when clicked, show the array of contacts in that particular hash?

At the moment I only have:

```
<% @lists.map do |list| %>
<% list.contacts.each do |contact| %>
```

This shows the contacts for every list, but how do I make only the selected lists' contacts show? I was thinking I could make the display to none for each container div and then when clicked, set that specific div to show - is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: More efficient? How about JQuery?

Comment: "is there a more efficient way" - why do you feel this one is not efficient enough?